# apache atlas，When I used Impala, Spark and Presto to operate Hive, I found that I could not participate in the Hive hook competition

Tags: hive, presto, impala, apache-atlas

I'm testing the Apache Atlas Hive function. Our company operates hive with Presto Impala, and Atlas can't find the tables or blood ties created by Presto Impala. The reason is that Presto Impala will not produce Hive hook when operating Hive. Have you encountered such a situation?

Comment: Do you mean Presto, Impala or "Presto Impala"?